# how to add a back arrow button of toolbar on to the imageview

Tags: android

In my layout i have an image view at the top without the toolbar. I want to have the back arrow button of toolbar on my imageview, like whatsapp profile view with back arrow on the imageview.

i wanted this result[image]

i got the result by adding this

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following image and save it to drawable.

[image]

and use with the following code

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_arrow"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />
```

Comment: It should be in drawable-xhdpi otherwise it comes out WAY too large

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `Toolbar` like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back_button"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back_button" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

It will be like this .

[image]

Also , You will get the Icon from [here](https://design.google.com/icons/) .